# How can i read an s3 file without S3 SDK using aws credentials?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

so i want to read an S3 file using PHP without going to the url for security purposes.

I cannot use sdk since im using lambda and does not allow me to use php-filter and/or openssl 10.0.2

I found lots of Curl examples to put/post files but is there a way to do the get using all the credentials?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps you could look for a 3rd party PHP S3 client, for example https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class.

Comment: @jarmod thay may work, put it as an answer so if it works i can award you the points

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot use Lambda and you don't want to use API then the only option is to use CLI. As I am not a PHP guy I don't know will CLI works with PHP but give it a try. If you want to get object from S3 using CLI then see the sample below,

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket text-content --key dir/my_images.tar.bz2 my_images.tar.bz2
```

Please read the documentation - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html

Comment: Get your point, but you think that i can use exec to run the CLI and then retrieve that Json for use?

Comment: If it is in C# I would have done the same like you have mentioned but I don't know about PHP. If you can use exec with PHP then yes can run CLI command.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a PHP library that will run in AWS Lambda and that can interface with Amazon S3. Amazon doesn't currently offer PHP language support in Lambda, so you might want to look at one of these options:

- 3rd-party PHP S3 client, for example [amazon-s3-php-class](http://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class)
- create your own S3 requests to the [S3 REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAPI.html)
- 3rd-party options for running PHP in Lambda (examples [here](https://github.com/dannylinden/aws-lambda-php) and [here](https://read.acloud.guru/serverless-php-630bb3e950f5))